ASP.NET Core Razor page favorite list with localstorage
Who can help me create a favorite list of teams for example that I can then display on another page and do this with local storage? The list comes from a SQL database.
At the end of the list (table) there is a heart icon, which you can click on. When you click on the heart icon it changes into another icon. But when I refresh the page I want to see the selected items again. Also, when I open another page, I get a list of my selected items.
teams.cshtml:
@page
@model organizer.Pages.TeamsModel
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@addTagHelper*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

@{
    Layout = "_Layout2";
}

<div class="eigentabel">
    <h3 class="text-end"> @Model.variabelTNaam</h3>
    @foreach (var itemD in Model.listDivisieD)
    {           
    //hier zetten we de titel op de pagina
        <span><h2>@itemD.naam </h2></span>
        <table id="" class="display">
        @{
        Model.nummer = 0;  
        }
        <thead>
            <tr>
                    <th style="width: 2%">#</th>
                <th style ="text-align: center; width: 2%"></th>
                <th style="text-align: left; width: 10%">Team name</th>
                <th style="width: 5%">Country</th>
                <th style="width: 5%">Payed on</th>
                <th style="width: 5%">Like</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
                <tbody>

            @foreach (var itemT in Model.listTeamT)
            {
            if (itemT.divisie == @itemD.naam)
            {
            <tr>
            @{
            Model.nummer = Model.nummer + 1; 
            }

                    <td>@Model.nummer</td>
                    <td><img src="https://@itemT.vlag" width="20" height="13"></td>
                    <td><a asp-page-handler="Team" asp-route-varTeamId="@itemT.id">@itemT.naam</a></td>
                    <td>@itemT.land</td>
                    <td>@itemT.betaling</td>
                    <td><i onclick="myFunction(this)" id="hartje" class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></td>
            </tr>
            }
        }
        </tbody>
        </table>
    }
</div>

teams.cshtml.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace organizer.Pages
{
    public class TeamsModel : PageModel
    {
        public String? variabelTNaam;
        public List<TeamInfoT> listTeamT = new();
        public List<DivisieInfoD> listDivisieD = new();
        public string? sessionvarTorId;
        public int nummer;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        //Dit moeten we hier zetten en de variabele instellen
        public void OnGetTeamAsync(Guid? varTeamId)
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("SessionTeamId", varTeamId.ToString());
            Response.Redirect("/Team_detail"); 
        }

        public TeamsModel(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            // Set value in Session object.
            if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("SessionTorId") != null)
                sessionvarTorId = HttpContext.Session.GetString("SessionTorId");
                
            try
            {
                string connString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
                using SqlConnection connection = new(connString);
                connection.Open();
                String sqlD = "SELECT  .....";
                String sqlT = "SELECT ...";
                String sql1 = "SELECT ...";

                using SqlCommand command1 = new(sql1, connection);
                variabelTNaam = (string)command1.ExecuteScalar();

                using (SqlCommand commandD = new(sqlD, connection))
                {
                    using SqlDataReader readerD = commandD.ExecuteReader();

                    while (readerD.Read())
                    {
                        DivisieInfoD divisieInfoD = new()
                        {
                            id = readerD.GetGuid(0),
                            naam = readerD.GetString(2),
                            maxTeams = readerD.GetInt32(14),
                        };

                        listDivisieD.Add(divisieInfoD);
                    }
                }

                using SqlCommand commandT = new(sqlT, connection);
                { 
                    using SqlDataReader readerT = commandT.ExecuteReader();

                    while (readerT.Read())
                    {
                        TeamInfoT teamInfoT = new()
                        {
                            id = readerT.GetGuid(0),
                            naam = readerT.GetString(1),
                            land = readerT.GetString(2),
                            vlag = readerT.GetString(3).ToString().ToLower().Replace(" ", "_"),
                            betaling = readerT.IsDBNull(4) ? "-" : readerT.GetDateTime(4).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"),
                            divisie = readerT.GetString(5),
                        };
                    
                        listTeamT.Add(teamInfoT);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("NOT Connected"); 
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: connectie NIET ok " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    public class DivisieInfoD
    {
        public String? naam;
        public Guid? id;
        public int maxTeams;
    }

    public class TeamInfoT
    {
        public Guid id;
        public String? naam;
        public String? land;
        public String? vlag;
        public String? betaling;
        public String? divisie;
    }
}

_layout2.cshtml:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - TEST</title>

    <!-- DataTables -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/js/datatables.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" />
    <link href="~/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
   
<body>
    <header>
     <div class="fixed-top"> 
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm bg-primary navbar-dark border-bottom box-shadow mb-3 ">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-left">
                    <a class="navbar-brand"  target="_blank">                     
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-right">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-end">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-light " style="margin-left:1em" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index"><span class="fa fa-home"></span> Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-light " style="margin-left:1em" asp-area="" asp-page="/Tornooi_Algemeen"><span class="fa fa-dashboard"></span> Dashboard</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy;  - <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //function changing heart
        function myFunction(x) {
            x.classList.toggle("fa-thumbs-up");
            window.localStorage.setItem("FavoriteTeam", "test");
        }

        // Initialize the DataTable
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('table.display').DataTable({
                // Set the number of rows to be
                // displayed per page on the DataTable
                pageLength: 25,
                lengthMenu: [25, 50]
            });
        });

        // Initialize the DataTable
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('table.display2').DataTable({
 
        "dom": "<'row'<'col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-xs-12'f><'col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-12'l>>" +
                    "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                    "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>",

                // Set the number of rows to be
                // displayed per page on the DataTable
                pageLength: 25,
                lengthMenu: [25, 50, 100]
            });
        });
    </script>

    <!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-4CPZWF653F"></script>
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
        gtag('js', new Date());

        gtag('config', 'G-4CPZWF653F');
    </script>



    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>


You could try below code:
Data/ApplicationDbContext.cs:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace FavoriteTeams.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
               : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Division> Divisions { get; set; }
    }

    public class Team
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Flag { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Payment { get; set; }
        public Guid DivisionId { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public Division Division { get; set; }
    }

    public class Division
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int MaxTeams { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    }

}

Data/DbInitializer.cs:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace FavoriteTeams.Data
{
    public class DbInitializer
    {
        public static void Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext(
                serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>>()))
            {
                if (context.Divisions.Any() || context.Teams.Any())
                {
                    return;   // DB has been seeded
                }

                var divisions = new Division[]
                {
                       new Division { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Division 1", MaxTeams = 10 },
                       new Division { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Division 2", MaxTeams = 10 }
                };

                foreach (var d in divisions)
                {
                    context.Divisions.Add(d);
                }

                context.SaveChanges();

                var teams = new Team[]
                {
                       new Team { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Team 1", Country = "Country 1", Flag = "flag_url_1", Payment = DateTime.Now, DivisionId = divisions[0].Id },
                       new Team { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Team 2", Country = "Country 2", Flag = "flag_url_2", Payment = DateTime.Now, DivisionId = divisions[1].Id }
                };

                foreach (var t in teams)
                {
                    context.Teams.Add(t);
                }

                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

}

Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - FavoriteTeams</title>
   @*  <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> *@
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/FavoriteTeams.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <!-- DataTables CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">FavoriteTeams</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2024 - FavoriteTeams - <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>

    @* <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script> *@

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <!-- DataTables JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>

Pages/Teams.cshtml:
@page
@model FavoriteTeams.Pages.TeamsModel
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<div class="eigentabel">
    <h3 class="text-end">Teams Overview</h3>
    @foreach (var division in Model.Divisions)
    {
        <span><h2>@division.Name </h2></span>
        <table id="teamsTable-@division.Id" class="display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 2%">#</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center; width: 2%"></th>
                    <th style="text-align: left; width: 10%">Team name</th>
                    <th style="width: 5%">Country</th>
                    <th style="width: 5%">Payed on</th>
                    <th style="width: 5%">Like</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @{
                    var num = 0;
                }
                @foreach (var team in Model.Teams.Where(t => t.DivisionId == division.Id))
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@(++num)</td>
                        <td><img src="https://@team.Flag" width="20" height="13"></td>
                        <td>@team.Name</td>
                        <td>@team.Country</td>
                        <td>@(team.Payment.HasValue ? team.Payment.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") : "-")</td>
                        <td><i onclick="toggleFavorite('@team.Id', this)" class="fa fa-heart-o heart-icon" data-team-id="@team.Id"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function toggleFavorite(teamId, element) {
            const favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favoriteTeams')) || [];
            const index = favorites.indexOf(teamId);

            if (index === -1) {
                favorites.push(teamId);
                element.classList.remove("fa-heart-o");
                element.classList.add("fa-heart");
            } else {
                favorites.splice(index, 1);
                element.classList.remove("fa-heart");
                element.classList.add("fa-heart-o");
            }

            localStorage.setItem('favoriteTeams', JSON.stringify(favorites));
        }

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            const favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favoriteTeams')) || [];
            const icons = document.querySelectorAll('.heart-icon');

            icons.forEach(icon => {
                const teamId = icon.getAttribute('data-team-id');
                if (favorites.includes(teamId)) {
                    icon.classList.remove('fa-heart-o');
                    icon.classList.add('fa-heart');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}

Teams.cshtml.cs:
using FavoriteTeams.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace FavoriteTeams.Pages
{
    public class TeamsModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public TeamsModel(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IList<Team> Teams { get; set; }
        public IList<Division> Divisions { get; set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            Teams = await _context.Teams.Include(t => t.Division).ToListAsync();
            Divisions = await _context.Divisions.ToListAsync();
        }


    }
}

Pages/FavoriteTeams.cshtml:
@page
@model FavoriteTeams.Pages.FavoriteTeamsModel
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Favorite Teams</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Favorite Teams</h1>
    <div id="favoriteTeamsContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
            const favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favoriteTeams')) || [];
            console.log('Favorites from local storage:', favorites);

            const allTeams = @Html.Raw(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.Teams));
            console.log('All Teams:', allTeams);

            // Log the structure of allTeams
            console.log('Structure of allTeams:', JSON.stringify(allTeams, null, 2));

            if (Array.isArray(allTeams)) {
                favorites.forEach(favoriteId => {
                    console.log('Processing favorite teamId:', favoriteId);
                    const team = allTeams.find(t => {
                        console.log('Checking team:', t);
                        console.log('Favorite Team ID:', favoriteId);
                        if (t && t.Id) {
                            console.log('Current Team ID:', t.Id);
                            const idsMatch = t.Id.toLowerCase() === favoriteId.toLowerCase();
                            console.log('IDs match:', idsMatch);
                            return idsMatch;
                        } else {
                            console.error('Team or Team ID is undefined:', t);
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    console.log('Found team:', team);
                    if (team) {
                        const teamElement = document.createElement('div');
                        teamElement.innerHTML = `
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="https://${team.Flag}" width="20" height="13">
                                        <a href="/Team_detail?varTeamId=${team.Id}">${team.Name}</a>
                                        <span>${team.Country}</span>
                                        <span>${team.Payment}</span>
                                    </div>
                                `;
                        console.log('Appending team element to container:', teamElement);
                        document.getElementById('favoriteTeamsContainer').appendChild(teamElement);
                    } else {
                        console.error('Team not found:', favoriteId);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.error('allTeams is not an array');
            }
        });
    </script>
}

FavoriteTeams.cshtml.cs:
using FavoriteTeams.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace FavoriteTeams.Pages
{
    public class FavoriteTeamsModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public List<Team> Teams { get; set; }

        public FavoriteTeamsModel(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            Teams = _context.Teams.Include(t => t.Division).ToList();
        }


    }
}

Program.cs:
using FavoriteTeams.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
       options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
builder.Services.AddSession();


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

SeedDatabase(app);


app.Run();
static void SeedDatabase(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
    {
        DbInitializer.Initialize(serviceScope.ServiceProvider);
    }
}




I get an error, Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Models' does not exist in the namespace '.......organizer' (are you missing an assembly reference?) ...........
My project is a ASP.net core Razorpage

@New'asp.netcore'One you can add the refer to your Models like organizer.TeamsModel i have used name favlist for my project name so my Model reference looks like favlist.Models;

Hi,
I managed to remember my hearts, perfect, thx. But it is not yet possible to retrieve the data from the local storage. I get a blank web page. And I don't get any error message either. How do I best debug this?

The connection string is ok. I have 1282 teams in the listTeamT1.
I think the problem is that my script is not working or is incorrectly configured.
If I debug I see that there are no teams in const allTeams. This is the problem.

TeamsModel.cs I still getting an error on 'using organizer.Data;
using organizer.Models;   CS0246

@New'asp.netcore'One i will retest the code and update you soon

@New'asp.netcore'One i have updated whole code try this and test with the limited data first and see the result

I get an Exception Unhandled: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'Divisions'.'

Hi,I used the first code and it works fine. The issue was the sql-statement.
